# HREF link for Excel Files Generated using PHP

Tags: php, seo

I would like to get your inputs on the "preferred" way of linking to dynamically generated excel files using PHP.

Using PHPExcel (or any other Excel writer for that matter) I have to generate a downloadable Excel file with PHP. The obvious method would be to create a link to that PHP file with a parameter such as

```
<a href="download.php?data=gdp">Download GDP figures</a>
```

However, for SEO purposes, the preferred method **I think** would be:

```
<a href="country_gdp.xls">Download GDP figures</a>
```

especially if advanced users (such as researchers) use the Google Search parameter **filetype:xls** in their searches.

Note that I am NOT an SEO expert and I don't have any evidence the latter is better. However I would assume the 2nd method would be more searchable than the first even by a small degree.  The problem of course is that I don't know how to generate the Excel file dynamically using this 2nd method.

So is the 1st method acceptable and I'm just trying to complicate things? Or would you go for the 2nd method and have a workaround to call a PHP script to generate the excel file dynamically?

Comment: I'm also not a SEO expert and don't know if the latter method is better. But you can achieve it using `mod_rewrite`

Comment: This is a programming question. I don't believe it should have been migrated.

Comment: @Homer6 Me too.  I believe my question is for a web programmer rather than a web administrator (or someone managing existing sites already)

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes I've thought about mod_rewrite. But I'm actually thinking how complex that may be since our site also contains other downloable files such as pds and videos

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that Google probably sees both documents correctly as a xls spreadsheet (provided that the Content-Type headers on the download.php url are set correctly).

However, generating the file will mean you'll have to decide where to store it. If you store it on the filesystem, you'll limit your ability to have more than one web server. If you store it in the database, you could be bloating your database a bit. If you store it on a CDN, there will be some latency while the file is propagated (from the time it's requested or generated).

But since you asked what my *preferred* method is, this is what I do. I don't like tying up the UI waiting for reports to generate. Where I work, some reports take several minutes to generate and tying them to the UI is error prone because if the user exits, it'll end the generation prematurely. Even though this may add complexity, I prefer to use RabbitMQ to decouple the events (ie. a generate report event from a user or a cron) from the work (ie. a process creating a report). RabbitMQ (or some similar message-bus architecture) also allows you to easily parallelize report generation (if there are a large number of them). Then, once the report has been generated, you can use one of the three storage methods (mentioned above) to store the generated report, safe in the knowledge that it's decoupled from your user's interaction. Caching even a little bit can help quite a bit (especially on a busy site). Users often don't mind a report to be *a little* stale. However, it very much depends on the nature of the report. If it's an operations report, it may be required to be up to the minute. In which case, there may be little room for pre-generating your reports. Also, if there are many different variables as inputs to the report, it may be infeasible to generate given the broad scope of the permutations.

Lastly, if the report generation is costly (in time, cpu, etc.), there is another hybrid option. You may be able to pre-summarize *part* of your report. If the latency-intensive part can be pre-calculated and the "up-to-the-minute" part of your report can use that information to quickly generate the report, then you may be able to directly generate the report from the user's request. With that, there are few more moving parts (such as invalidating the presummarization if the data changes). However, for records from the past (such as telemetry data), the data doesn't change. So, it's a great candidate for presummarization.

Sorry for the long response. Hope this helps.

Comment: potentially a +1 post. `mod_rewrite` should being mentioned

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informative answer. Though it didn't answer my question directly, it gave me a lot to think about. I have only considered the SEO aspect, but up to now haven't considered the performance and storage aspects. Our site's downloadable data and number of users are not (yet) that considerable, so message bus architectures (which I dont know anything about) and CDNs are not needed. But your suggestion of presummarization is interesting and can be explored with all our reports. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a question in an Excel file generating speed.
If your .xls is generated quickly - you may use the dynamic method.
But it not preferrable, because you need to build your excel file every time the script called.
The better way is to use cron script (if you need to update your xls) that generates your xls file and rewrites it in static location.

So I bet you will choose the second option with cron task generating the .xls file.

Have a nice day!

Comment: have you ever heard about `mod_rewrite`? Sorry for down-vote but your solution makes things too complicated

Comment: yes, of course I've heard of it. but I prefer to use NGinx and I do not need to use dynamic .xls generation because it is all about time. when you use cron tasks - you do not need to generate static xls file every time the script called. your web server just serving static xls file, which is more faster than generate it dynamically on each request

Comment: why not prerendering all your php pages? you could store them as HTML in filesystem

Comment: of course you can use memcached/redis for this kind of tasks. the filesystem is slower than RAM, you know this

Comment: This was a joke. If you wan't to optimize speed, use a caching http proxy between web server and clients. I see no difference between generating HTML pages or generating xls files dynamically. There is no need to store them on filesystem. When the page accepts multiple params it will get really weird as the number of documents to be rendered rises exponentially with the number of params and possible values.

Comment: good joke) Generating xls files is more complex task than generating an html page, especially using PHPExcel, especially, if you use .xls (not .xlsx) type of spreadsheets. What about 200 000 records? Maybe .csv? )) and by the way - there is no words about params in the question

Comment: As I told, use a caching proxy if you want a transparent, nice to administrate solution. Prerendering isn't even an option in the most places. Image that SO for example would support xls download of reputation per user per day.. This would be (just for a year) 365 days * 2.000.000 users documents. many documents! arent't it? and most of them will never being downloaded.

Comment: IMO, what you are suggesting defeats the principals of a dynamic web page. Caching should not being done on application-level

Comment: Of course you _must_ use caching proxy, but dynamic generation of .xls file is not a good idea in any way. And caching should be done not just on one level. It must be done on application level such as on server level.

Comment: I don't see any problem with dynamic generation of the xls file. Even PHP creating an mp3 dynamically would be ok for me. however, sometimes opinions differ. don't take the down-vote personal. cu!

Comment: oh, no))) sure, I don't even see this downvote))) I just prefer the "highload" way of managing server and its content. What will you do with 10 000 concurrent requests on your xls generating script?

Comment: IMO it is unlikely that this 10.000 requests will all want to download the same version of the `xls`.. It is likely that the urls will look like `generator.php?user=123&param2=...` This fact could be the first limit depending on the number of users and possible options of param2 (etc). Also note, what Homer6 has said in his answer: If you wan't a scalable solution, using clustered web server, you'll have to make sure that the documents are available (in the same state) on every server. You see, things get weird, at least from this point.

Comment: yes, you are perfectly right - it is all about particular tasks.

Comment: yes definitely ...